# Can I use a property of the result of a function as a decorator?

Tags: python

I've made myself a simple event system in python, and I found that the way I fired the events was pretty much the same every time: either at the end of a call, or before it. It felt like this would be a nice thing to have as a decorator. Here's the code I'm using:

```
from functools import wraps

def fires(event):
    """
    Returns a decorater that causes an `Event` to fire immediately before the
    decorated function is called
    """
    def beforeDecorator(f):
        """Fires the event before the function executes"""
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
            event.fire(*args, **kargs)
            return f(*args, **kargs)
        return wrapped

    def afterDecorator(f):
        """Fires the event after the function executes"""
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
            result = f(*args, **kargs)
            event.fire(*args, **kargs)
            return result
        return wrapped

    # Should allow more explicit `@fires(event).uponCompletion` and
    # `@fires(event).whenCalled`
    afterDecorator.onceComplete = afterDecorator
    afterDecorator.whenCalled = afterDecorator

    return afterDecorator
```

With this code, I can successfully write this:

```
@fires(myEvent)
def foo(y):
    return y*y

print func(2)
```

And everything works. The problem comes when I try to write this:

```
@fires(myEvent).onceComplete
def foo(y):
    return y*y

print func(2)
```

That gives me a syntax error. Is there some special syntax for complex decorators? Does the parser stop after the first set of parentheses?

Comment: Not just any expression can be used as a decorator.  For example `@(lambda f: f())` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, according to the [grammar specification](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-funcdef), not possible:

```
funcdef        ::=  [decorators] "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")" ["->" expression] ":" suite
decorators     ::=  decorator+
decorator      ::=  "@" dotted_name ["(" [argument_list [","]] ")"] NEWLINE
dotted_name    ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    (  "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)*
                    [, "**" parameter]
                    | "**" parameter
                    | defparameter [","] )
parameter      ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
funcname       ::=  identifier
```

Decorators must have their parentheses at the end

Answer (score 2):

I added pre-computation of your before and after variants (thanks to the invoke trick, all the closures are created at import-time and simply used whenever the decorator is applied), made the choice dependent on an optional argument to the meta-decorator, and put in a try/finally block to make sure your after-events always fire.  With this approach the question of function attributes becomes moot.

```
invoke = lambda f: f()  # trick used in JavaScript frameworks all the time

@invoke  # closure becomes fires
def fires():
    def beforeDecorator(f, event):
        """Fires the event before the function executes"""
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
            event.fire(*args, **kargs)
            return f(*args, **kargs)
        return wrapped

    def afterDecorator(f, event):
        """Fires the event after the function executes"""
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
            try:
              result = f(*args, **kargs)
            finally:
              event.fire(*args, **kargs)
            return result
        return wrapped

    def closure(event, after=False):  # becomes fires
      def decorator(function):
        if after:
            return afterDecorator(function, event)
        else:
            return beforeDecorator(function, event)
      return decorator
    return closure
```

Comment: Surely that will call the original `fires` with no arguments, since `invoke(fires)` is called, which expands to `fires()`, which in turn will error, since the `event` argument is missing.

Comment: The `@invoke` decorator causes the inner function `closure` to replace the original `fires`.  So once it's defined you can decorate things with `@fires(myevent, True)` and it will fire after.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now that you've moved the arguments. Are you sure it's an improvement though? @invoke looks like a hack. Feels like I should just use a class to wrap both versions.

Comment: The only thing it buys you over FJ's version is that the before and after decorators aren't created every time `fires` is called.  If you dynamically create functions at run time that are decorated with `@fires` then that would be a performance improvement.  Otherwise, take or leave.

Comment: And while I use `@invoke` in my own stuff, I have not seen it in other Python frameworks.  However `Node.js` in the AJAX world uses an identical technique constantly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a way to get the syntax you want to work, but here is an alternative.

Just add an additional argument to your `fires()` decorator to determine whether it should happen before or after:

```
def fires(event, before=True):
    """
    Returns a decorater that causes an `Event` to fire immediately before or
    after the decorated function is called
    """
    if before:
        def decorator(f):
            """Fires the event before the function executes"""
            @wraps(f)
            def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
                event.fire(*args, **kargs)
                return f(*args, **kargs)
            return wrapped
    else:
        def decorator(f):
            """Fires the event after the function executes"""
            @wraps(f)
            def wrapped(*args, **kargs):
                result = f(*args, **kargs)
                event.fire(*args, **kargs)
                return result
            return wrapped

    return decorator
```

And then use it like this:

```
@fires(myEvent, before=False)   # or before=True, defaults to True
def foo(y):
    return y*y
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing this, but it feels cleaner the other way around. If I have to go this way, I'll probably go for `@fires.whenCalled(myEvent)`